# Regular expression for Entity framework model

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I need to add regular expression data annotation on asp.net MVC 3 model ( I am using Entity frame work 4.1 code first).

Requirement is:

```
Capitalize matters. use 6 to 32 characters and don’t use your name.
To make your password more secure:- use special characters (e.g., @) – mix lower and upper case.
```

Please suggest me the regular expression or tool to create one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you the [following article](http://www.zorched.net/2009/05/08/password-strength-validation-with-regular-expressions/) for designing a regular expression that will match your requirements. If you encounter some specific difficulties don't hesitate to show your progress and explain the problems you are encountering.

As far as the *username doesn't match your name* requirement is concerned you will have to provide far more information about what *real name* means, where is it stored, how do you retrieve it, ...